# Json retorna vazio (web service com Jersey)

Tags: web-service, java-ee, jersey

Estou desenvolvendo um web service usando Jersey e o Json retornado por um dos métodos está vindo vazio. O mais estranho é que os outros métodos estão seguindo a mesma lógica e estão funcionando corretamente. Fiz um debug e verifiquei que os dados são retornados do banco e a minha lista com os objetos é criada corretamente e que o response contém a lista. Segue o código:

**Método que fica na classe dos recursos**

```
        @GET
        @Path("/retornaAluno/{nomeEscola}/{codigoResponsavel}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response retornaAluno(@PathParam("nomeEscola") String nomeEscola, @PathParam("codigoResponsavel") String codigoResponsavel) {
            Response response;
            ArrayList<Aluno> listaAluno = new Controler().retornaAluno(nomeEscola, codigoResponsavel);
            if(listaAluno != null){
                logger.info("Resposta do retornaAluno enviada com sucesso");
                //se no entity eu colocar algum texto, por exemplo, no json é exibido corretamente
                response = Response.status(200).entity(listaAluno).build();
                return response;
            }else{
                logger.info(MSG_COD_RESP_NAO_ENCONTRADO);
                response = Response.status(200).entity(MSG_COD_RESP_NAO_ENCONTRADO).build();
                return response;
            }
        }
```

**Método que fica na classe que faz a parte do controler**

```
    public ArrayList<Aluno> retornaAluno(String nomeEscola, String codigoResponsavel) {
            ArrayList<Aluno> listaAluno = new WSDao(nomeEscola).retornaAluno(codigoResponsavel);
            return listaAluno;
    }
```

**Método que fica na classe que se comunica com o banco**

```
    public ArrayList<Aluno> retornaAluno(String codigoResponsavel) {
            try {
                if(!verificaCodigoNoMetodo(codigoResponsavel).equals("0")){
                    ArrayList<Aluno> listaAluno = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
                    String sql = "SELECT A.ID, A.NOME, A.SERIE, A.TURMA FROM TB_ALUNO A INNER JOIN TB_ALUNO_RESPONSAVEL B ON B.ALUNO_ID = A.ID " 
                    + "INNER JOIN TB_CODIGO C ON B.RESPONSAVEL_ID = C.RESPONSAVELID WHERE C.IDALUNO IS NULL AND C.CODIGO = ?";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    stmt.setString(1, codigoResponsavel);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    while(rs.next()){
                        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
                        aluno.setIdAluno(rs.getInt("id"));
                        aluno.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                        aluno.setSerie(rs.getString("serie"));
                        aluno.setTurma(rs.getString("turma"));
                        listaAluno.add(aluno);
                    }

                    stmt.close();
                    rs.close();
                    connection.close();
                    logger.info("retornaAluno chamado com sucesso.");
                    return listaAluno;
                }else{
                    logger.info("retornaAluno chamado com sucesso.");
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Ocorreu uma falha na consulta no método retornaAluno", e);
                throw new RuntimeException("Ocorreu uma falha na consulta no método retornaAluno");
            }
    }
```

**Classe Aluno**

```
package Bean;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Aluno {

    private String nome;
    private String codigo;
    private String serie;
    private String turma;
    private int idAluno;

    public void setSerie(String serie) {
        this.serie = serie;
    }

    public void setTurma(String turma) {
        this.turma = turma;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public void setIdAluno(int idAluno) {
        this.idAluno = idAluno;
    }
}
```

**Arquivo web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Nome_do_projeto</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>pacote_onde_fica_os_recursos</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jContextName</param-name>
    <param-value>Nome_do_projeto</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Como o json está sendo retornado quando tento retornar apenas um objeto, por exemplo**

```
[
  {}
]
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. O problema estava na classe Aluno. Eu havia removido os métodos get de cada atributo, pois não estavam sendo usados em lugar nenhum do meu código, mas ao colocar de voltar os métodos get dos atributos na classe Aluno os dados voltaram a aparecer no Json. Por algum motivo na hora de serializar o Jersey usa os métodos get dos atributos, então a dica é: se utilizar Jersey para construir um web service nas classes Bean deixem os métodos get mesmo que não sejam usados por outras classes.

Comment: Postei como resposta a resolução do problema, assim você ajuda outras pessoas que venham a ter o mesmo problema.